# I have to use session in my login page and profile page

Tags: html, sql-server, iis

I have an index.php

```
<?php
 SESSION_START();

    if ( $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {



           Profile page content.......



    }
    else{
          $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false;
          header('Location:/login.php');    
     }
```

i have the login.php

```
<?php
  SESSION_START();
 ?>
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <base href="/"> 
 <body style="background-color: #f1f1f1;">
    <form  name="myForm"  method="post" action="logincheck.php">
     userid<input type="text"name="usename">
     <br>password<input typy="password" name="password">
      <br>
     <input type="submit"name="submit"value="login">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and i have Logincheck.php

```
     <?php  
      SESSION_START();
      $uname = $_POST['username'];                                                                                      
      $pword = $_POST['password'];
      $serverName = "ipaddress,portnumber";                                                                                 
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testing", 
                              "UID"=>"username","PWD"=>"password");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
         if( $conn )  
        {   
            $params = array($uname, $pword);                    
            $sqlquery="select username from emp where username=? and 
                         password=?";

            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlquery,$params);

            $count=sqlsrv_has_rows($query);     

            if ($count ===false )
                {
                    $_SESSION['error']=true;
                    header('Location:/login.php');                                                                              

                }
                else
                {   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['user']=$_POST['username'];   
                     header("Location: /index.php?$uname");                                                                     

                }  
               sqlsrv_close($con);                                                                                          

        }else{
            echo"<h1 >Database Connection Error...</h1>";                                                               
        }
   ?>
```

i dont have problem with all these except index.php. because this is not redirecting to any page this is showing error like

**This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

i didnt get the solution.
can any pull me out from this problem.

Comment: the problem:
header("Location: /index.php?$uname");

Correct:
header("Location: /index.php?" . $uname);

Comment: Thank you for responds. but that was not the problem. The problem is whenever i open my project using name called localhost means i am  trying to open index.php then it is showing error 500. means problem with index page.   This is my explanation Now you can try your answer .# A. M. Mérida

Comment: the error "500 Internal Server Error",  is shown if your php code has fatal errors but error displaying is switched off.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. i got the answer. that i have keep all the html code directly in php code (index.php) without using echo.